# Some UTF-8 characters shown as a question mark in my spring annotaded Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7

when i show this characters in the sysout in main method everything works fine and console shows characters properly. But when i put exact same sysout in my spring annotated controller it shows question marks instead. here is the code

System.out.println("əışçğ");

Please keep in mind that i just put static data in my controller for showing it. There is no any protocol or form submission that sends data. i just put above sysout code in my controller and it gives me bunch of question marks. Please help

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: one week googled and found nothing about it. people had a problem when they submit forms and they add filter in order to solve it. But my problem is the spring controller somehow is not able to process the utf8 characters. It just convert those characters to question marks. But when i put same code in main method it shows all the charecters properly.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the characters are being displayed in different fonts. Not all fonts support all the UTF-8 characters. I ran into this with Arial recently, where Arial Unicode MS was not installed and the client defaulted to Arial.

Comment: İ checked fonts. it is consolas. And tried other fonts as well but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

put this in your web.xml and redeploy

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: i already putted it in my web.xml and my jsp meta files charset also set to utf8 and also my tomcat server Connector tags include uriEncoding="utf-8". But the problem is, i don't accept any data from url or from form submission. I just write these 5 (ğ,ə,ı,ş,ç ) letters in my controller and run it but it shows question mark but when i put same static data in my java main method it shows all the characters properly. I strongly believe that there is something i should add in my dispetcher-servlet.xml but i don't know what. because problem happens inside of the controller

Comment: so far i put these beans in my dispetcher-servlet.xml but they didn't solve the problem. 
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" >
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <beans:property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your mavn and try again after build and redeploy. Btw, which ide u r using??

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
</properties>
```

Comment: i am using eclipse and my maven alredy includes                          <properties>                                       
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
 </properties>

Comment: Yes add in pom.xml